# Python 2.7 cannot import name <class>

Tags: python, oop

I have a simple module (python 2.7) from which I'm trying to import a class, but I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Engine
```

My code is:

```
from components import Engine
```

and in components:

```
class Engine(object):
    pass
```

On the other hand

```
from components import *
```

works fine

What an I doing wrong? Any hints appreciated

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to reproduce the problem, but you might have a cyclic import or you might be importing the wrong `components` file.

Comment: Thanks. I've created a simple structure as Juan suggested below and it works. I think I must have a cyclic import somewhere - hard to spot, but I'll get to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this structure:

```
.
├── components
│   ├── Engine.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

And for example `main.py` is:

```
from components import Engine
print 'Hi'
```

And `Engine.py` is:

```
class Engine(object):
   pass
```

You mustn't find any problem with import statement.
The code run fine:

```
> python main.py 
Hi
```